# R from anaconda / Jupyter notebook doesn't work anymore

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a jupyter notebook installed from anaconda. 
And the R kernel just keeps dying :(

The error:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/home/jennifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
>     /home/jennifer/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/../../lib/../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/jennifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/stringi/libs/stringi.so)
>   Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
>   Execution halted

Also when I try to use the R also installed from anaconda, I cannot seem to get the packages installed.

Here is an example from when I tried to install devtools

> install.packages("devtools")
>
> Installing package into ‘/home/jennifer/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
>
> Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>
> error: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
>       /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./lib/tcl8.5 ./library ./library ./tcl8.5.18/library ./tcl8.5.18/library

Thanks in advance!